# How to determine the real URL of my website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress installation at `http://example.com` and many other Wordpress installations in directories (`http://example.com/my_dir_X`).
How can I know in PHP in which directory I am?

Comment: `http://example.com/my_dir_X` is not a directory. It's a host name. Do you need to know the host or the actual disk directory the file is in?

Comment: Look into [`$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should do it as well

Comment: @apokryfos yes you are right, this is a host name, but it is also a directory where the wordpress is installed :)

Comment: @AliAlwash nope, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = /home/ab454567/public_html/example.com

Comment: @aynber thanks, but for some reason, $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is empty..

Comment: @wp42 I am saying that a directory would be something like `/var/www/my_dir_x` (not `http://example.com/my_dir_x`) is that what you need or do you need the current hostname?

Comment: @apokryfos in the root (public_html) I have a directory named my_dir. ican access it via http://example.com/my_dir, right? so i need to know if I'm at my_dir_1 or my_dir_2.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this code, and it will echo it out on the frontend

```
<?php echo site_url(); ?>
```

or to echo out in the dashboard admin bar you could try something like this in functions.php

```
// add links/menus to the admin bar
function mytheme_admin_bar_render() {
global $wp_admin_bar;
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'parent' => 'new-content', // use 'false' for a root menu, or pass the ID of the parent menu
    'id' => 'new_media', // link ID, defaults to a sanitized title value
    'title' => site_url(), // link title
    'href' => echo site_url(), // name of file
    'meta' => false // array of any of the following options: array( 'html' 
=> '', 'class' => '', 'onclick' => '', target => '', title => '' );
    ));
}
add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'mytheme_admin_bar_render' );
```

Comment: You won't be able to see it in your php code as that data will only be stored in your sql files.  Perhaps you can echo it out in the wordpress dashboard but other than that it's just a case of checking your file structure

Comment: @ColinGell Thanks, site_url() is not perfect, but it's actually doing the job in my case. I will accept this answer if I don't get any better. (that works outside of Wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Use this function:

```
<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>
```

Or:

`<?php echo home_url(); ?>`

You can read more about the function get_site_url() here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/

And about home_url() here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

get_site_url() is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers you gave to others, this is the solution I came up with.

```
<?php
// Just to show you how it works, I'm overwriting the $_SERVER values, in your case you can directly use the values from $_SERVER
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com';
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/home/ab454567/public_html/example.com/my_dir_X/abc';

$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

preg_match('#^(.*)(/' . $domain . ')(?P<myDir>.*)#i', $fullPath, $matches);

if(isset($matches['myDir']) && !empty($matches['myDir'])) {
    echo "Found the root directory: " . $matches['myDir'] . PHP_EOL;
}
else {
    echo "No root dir found, probably I'm in the public_html root directory of the domain." . PHP_EOL;
}

// Output is: 
// Found the root directory: /my_dir_X/abc
```

This is your scenario, correct?

- Domain is www.example.com/my_dir_X
- You want to know which dir the website is in, so in this case /my_dir_X